# configuration error when installing rJava package

Tags: r

During installing rJava package, I got the following error messages:

> checking JNI data types... configure: error: One or more JNI types differ from the corresponding native type. You may need to use non-standard compiler flags or a different compiler in order to fix this.
>   ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’

May I know what is the cause for this failure and how to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: You should include a bit more information. For example, operating system, R version, Java version, ...

Answer (score 0):

If it installed but does not work try first  : remove.package("rJava") and the install.package("rJava"). Some times helps. If still ahvgin problem post more data. But unless it's not necessary.

EDIT : see also java path if it's correctly set up. Sometimes its messed up.